# Conservative Field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help with the following question . I have this vector field:

$$F(x,y):=y\frac{x^2\cos(xy)+y^2\cos(xy)-1}{x^2+y^2}\vec{i}+x\frac{x^2\cos(xy)+y^2\cos(xy)+1}{x^2+y^2}\vec{j}$$

and 2 domains:

$$D_1:=B_1(0) , D_2:=\{(x,y):(x-5)^{^2/_3}+(y-7)^{^2/_3}<1\}$$

I need to determine over which one the given F is a conservative field (of course prove it) and find its' potential function , and over which it is not conservative , in which case I need to supply a path within the domain that isn't equal to 0 .
Now, intuitively i figure that the first domain must be the non-conservative one because F won't be continuous at point (0,0) , other than that I have a hard time figuring out how to approach this question . I'd be grateful for some help !

Comment: This is the second time I've seen this exact same question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492017/q-determine-of-vector-field-is-conservative/

Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of a conservative vector field.  A vector field $F(x, y) = \langle P(x, y), Q(x, y) \rangle$ is conservative on some domain $D$ if $P_y = Q_x$, and the first order partial derivatives of $P$ and $Q$ are continuous on $D$.

To find the potential function for a conservative vector field $F$, you are looking for a scalar function $f$ such that $\nabla f = F$.  So in your case you would set
$$ f_x = y\frac{x^2 \cos(xy) + y^2 \cos(xy) - 1}{x^2 + y^2} = y \cos(xy) - \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}, $$ and
$$ f_y = x\frac{x^2 \cos(xy) + y^2 \cos(xy) + 1}{x^2 + y^2} = x \cos(xy) + \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}. $$
Can you solve for $f$ from here?

Comment: Should that not be $P_y=Q_x$?

Comment: @Daron Thank you.  Edited to fix.

Comment: so showing that $$F\in C^1$$ and $$P_y=Q_x$$ over a given domain should be enough to prove it's conservative?